# Always getting this as response to my command:: zsh: command not found: chsh

Tags: macos, terminal, command, zsh

Since I installed python to my Mac, I have a lot of trouble with zsh. By typing in something to the Terminal, I always get:

```
    zsh: command not found: {whatever I've typed}
```

Currently, my only way to get through that is to type:

```
      bash
```

and changing to bash profile.

The thing is, that I now wanted to learn about zsh. But I can't, because I don't even get into typing zsh commands.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What does `print $path` show? Have you created/edited `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` to modify your path?

Comment: @chepner thank's a lot for your reply. This is what I get for  `print $path`: `/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin`
Yes, once I edited `.zshrc` but I don't know how to get back. Do you have an idea?

Comment: If you did something like `PATH=/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin`, just replace it with `PATH=/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:$PATH`. (Also, put it in `.zprofile` instead of `.zshrc`.)

Comment: @chepner How should I do that? Just by typing this in the Terminal `PATH=/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:$PATH` and then executing it?

Comment: And why there is this `python@3.9` in the Path. I have no idea what I did :// Sorry

Comment: That's just how `brew` (I presume) installed Python 3.9, to keep it distinct from other versions of Python. You need to edit both `.zshrc` (to remove the assignment to `PATH`) and `.zprofile` (creating it if necessary, to add the correct assignment).

Comment: @chepner okay, I tried, but when I hit `vim ~/.zshrc` it says again: `zsh: command not found: vim`

Comment: Use `/usr/bin/vim` to avoid the need for path lookup.

Comment: @chepner Okay, got into the vim menu. What should I insert there?

Comment: This is not the place for a tutorial on editing a file.

Comment: @chepner Okay, sorry. But I don't know how to solve it. I'm in the vim menu. I hit `I` for inserting `PATH=/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:$PATH`. Then I hit `esc` and `:wq`to save and exit. But I just got a red mark: `E32: No file name´

Comment: Why are you using `vim` if you don't know how to use `vim`? You can use any editor you like to edit the *correct* files; this it the wrong forum to ask in if you don't know how to use *any* editor to edit a file.

Comment: @chepner Thank you a lot for your help. After trying and retrying it again and again and studying your answers, I finally got it.
I'm sorry for those problems. But by installing Flutter and Androidstudio by following a tutorial, I had to change something in vim. That's how I got into my problem. But now it's solved. Thank you again!

Comment: @binary_janik If your problem is solved, please write an answer explaining how you solved it and then accept your own answer. That way, this question doesn't stay open as unanswered and if anyone else in future has the same problem, then they can find the answer here to help them.